# Подскажите почему самопроизвольно расширяется размер сцены QGraphicsScene?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt5, pyqt5, qgraphicsscene

Господа, добрый день.
Подскажите почему самопроизвольно расширяется размер сцены QGraphicsScene? 
Я использую PyQt5 и хотел сделать анимацию, как элемент вращается на сцене
и заметил что она расширяется. Мне бы хотелось, что бы размер сцены не изменялся.
Вот мой код:

```
import json
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation, QObject, pyqtProperty, Qt, QLineF
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsItemGroup, QGraphicsRectItem




class Roads(QObject):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.road_group = QGraphicsItemGroup()

        with open("array_roads_file.json", "r") as read_file:
            road_net = json.load(read_file)

        pen = QPen(Qt.green, 4, Qt.SolidLine)
        rect_gr = QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 530, 530)
        rect_gr.setPen(pen)
        self.road_group.addToGroup(rect_gr)

        self.road_group.setScale(1)
        self._angle = 0

    @pyqtProperty(int)
    def angle(self):
        return self._angle


    @angle.setter
    def angle(self, value):
        self._angle = value
        self.road_group.setRotation(self._angle)

        pen2 = QPen(Qt.red, 4, Qt.SolidLine)
        scene = self.parent()
        scene.addLine(QLineF(scene.sceneRect().topLeft(), scene.sceneRect().topRight()), pen2)  # topline
        scene.addLine(QLineF(scene.sceneRect().topLeft(), scene.sceneRect().bottomLeft()), pen2)  # leftline
        scene.addLine(QLineF(scene.sceneRect().topRight(), scene.sceneRect().bottomRight()), pen2)  # rightline
        scene.addLine(QLineF(scene.sceneRect().bottomLeft(), scene.sceneRect().bottomRight()), pen2)  # bottomline




class Example(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


        self.initView()

    def initView(self):
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(self.scene)

        self.item = Roads(self.scene)
        self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self.item, b'angle')
        self.anim.setDuration(8000)
        self.anim.setStartValue(0)
        self.anim.setKeyValueAt(0.25, 90)
        self.anim.setKeyValueAt(0.5, 180)
        self.anim.setKeyValueAt(0.75, 270)
        self.anim.setEndValue(360)



        self.scene.addItem(self.item.road_group)

        self.setWindowTitle("Map animation")
        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 1000, 1000)

        self.anim.start()

        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 2):

[Попробуйте указывать размер сцене](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/3c2c4c45e2dadb105c37c1971412898161f04420/winapi__windows__ctypes/winapi_get_desktop_icon_list/get_desktop_icon_list_gui.py#L63) через [QGraphicsScene.setSceneRect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#sceneRect-prop).

Пример:

```
self.scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 600, 600)
```

Comment: красивее будет `self.scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 538, 538)` и `rect_gr = QGraphicsRectItem(4, 4, 530, 530)` :)

Comment: @S.Nick, пусть автор сам определит желаемый размер сцены :)

Comment: Господа спасибо большое за помощь. Очень помогло

Comment: @ИльяБенисович, это хорошо :) [А чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)